# open cover and finite subcover

Tags: general-topology

$B=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2 \leq 9\}-\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2  : x^2+y^2 \leq 4\}$

a) Sketch (or describe) $B$

b) Let $S=\{B((i,j),r):i,j \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } r \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Show that $S$ is an open cover of B and determine whether it has a finite subcover of $B$.

Of course there is no problem with part a) its a ring with $r_1=3$ and $r_2=2$  (here $r$ is radius) easy to draw, hard to explain though.

b) having problems of how to show that $S$ is an open cover of $B$.

Comment: S is an open cover off all $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the set $S=\{B((i,j),r):i,j∈Z and r∈N\}$ stands for the set of disks of open $\Bbb R^2$ with centre $(i, j)$ and radius $r$

Clearly $B \subseteq B(0,0) (4)$ which can be easily proven and which should be apparent if you have drawn these sets on the plane.

If $\mathscr A$ is a collection of sets and if $B$ is contained in at least one set in $\mathscr A$ then $B$ is definitely contained in $\bigcup_{a \in \mathscr A} A $.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for instance the open ball $B((0,0),100)$ alone covers the set $B$, so the set of all balls $B((i,j),r)$, where $i,j\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $r\in\mathbb{N}$, certainly covers $B$ (Thus it is an open cover).